# Glacier Tomato has twisted leaves

Tags: vegetables, leaves

I have multiple types of tomatoes planted in my greenhouse and all are healthy except for the Glacier type which has all the leaves twisted, even the new ones.  I only have one plant that is Glacier.
The color is still green and it looks healthy except for the twisting. I have looked for pests and can’t see anything
Can someone help me with this?
I do have pictures but I can’t figure out how to make them smaller.

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify, and post pictures if possible. One plant of the variety, One plant of the variety displaying the issue (and others of the same variety normal) or multiple plants of the variety, where all of the same variety have the same issue?

Comment: This link may be of use: https://ipm.missouri.edu/MEG/2019/7/tomatoLeafCurl/

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with "Glaicer type" tomatoes. Have you grown them before, with different results?

We grew 30+ varieties of heritage tomatoes in a commercial operation. Some of them just looked like crap! But that was normal for them.

In particular, we grew "Striped Roman" paste tomatoes. The leaves drooped and were curled *all the time!* They constantly looked like they were at death's door — even when climbing ten feet up and bearing barrow loads of tomatoes!

But when anything but the Striped Romans curled their leaves, it generally meant we were not watering consistently. It could be too much, or too little, or too much followed by too little — tomatoes can be very picky about their water needs!

Comment: I have not grown these before.  This is our first year with a greenhouse so we are still learning.  Any advice is welcome

Comment: Probably the biggest thing is to be very careful and consistent with watering, via drip-line or watering can at the base ONLY — do not wet the foliage! They generally need quite a bit of calcium and magnesium — we used dolomite lime and epson salts, which are both considered organic.